# How to define Decison table in DMN

Tags: camunda, business-process-management, dmn

How to define a Decision table in DMN designer such that,

This is one of the standard decisions : If claim amount is >10000 then hradmin approval =Y otherwise hradmin approval=N

Answer (score 1):

In DMN,

> a Decision table in DMN designer such that [...] If claim amount is >10000 then hradmin approval =Y otherwise hradmin approval=N

can be modeled as the following DRG for 1 InputData named `claim amount` and 1 Decision for the table named `hradmin approval`:

[image]

The `hradmin approval` decision table can be defined as follows:

[image]

The screenshot also shows sample data, matching your original requirements.

You can download the .dmn example here: https://kiegroup.github.io/kogito-online/?file=https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tarilabs/f9655e2f8a2c4253e66ce661e5c79879/raw/so69764028.dmn#/editor/dmn

Comment: I'm noticing only now, the question has a tag of specific vendor, but not clear if it's related to any vendor-specific features.
The answer I provided anyway is purely DMN based, so it should work the same or analogously on any DMN-enabled platform. Hope that helps anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can save the xml to a text file, upload it, try it out and modify it here: https://consulting.camunda.com/dmn-simulator/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="https://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20191111/MODEL/" xmlns:dmndi="https://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20191111/DMNDI/" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20180521/DC/" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DMN/20180521/DI/" xmlns:camunda="http://camunda.org/schema/1.0/dmn" id="dinnerDecisions" name="HR Approval Decision" namespace="http://camunda.org/schema/1.0/dmn" exporter="Camunda Modeler" exporterVersion="4.0.0">
  <decision id="beverages" name="HR Approval">
    <informationRequirement id="InformationRequirement_1xvojck">
      <requiredInput href="#InputData_0pgvdj9" />
    </informationRequirement>
    <decisionTable id="DecisionTable_07q05jb">
      <input id="InputClause_0bo3uen" label="Amount" camunda:inputVariable="">
        <inputExpression id="LiteralExpression_0d6l79o" typeRef="integer">
          <text>amount</text>
        </inputExpression>
      </input>
      <output id="OuputClause_99999" label="HR Approval" name="hrApproval" typeRef="boolean" />
      <rule id="row-506282952-7">
        <description></description>
        <inputEntry id="UnaryTests_0jb8hau">
          <text>&gt;10000</text>
        </inputEntry>
        <outputEntry id="LiteralExpression_1kr45vj">
          <text>true</text>
        </outputEntry>
      </rule>
      <rule id="DecisionRule_05oqdbw">
        <description></description>
        <inputEntry id="UnaryTests_1vcdz6c">
          <text>&lt;=10000</text>
        </inputEntry>
        <outputEntry id="LiteralExpression_0g5cscd">
          <text>false</text>
        </outputEntry>
      </rule>
    </decisionTable>
  </decision>
  <inputData id="InputData_0pgvdj9" name="Amount" />
  <dmndi:DMNDI>
    <dmndi:DMNDiagram id="DMNDiagram_0i21c0s">
      <dmndi:DMNShape id="DMNShape_0a1lk6d" dmnElementRef="beverages">
        <dc:Bounds height="80" width="180" x="430" y="130" />
      </dmndi:DMNShape>
      <dmndi:DMNEdge id="DMNEdge_1czaglz" dmnElementRef="InformationRequirement_1xvojck">
        <di:waypoint x="500" y="287" />
        <di:waypoint x="520" y="230" />
        <di:waypoint x="520" y="210" />
      </dmndi:DMNEdge>
      <dmndi:DMNShape id="DMNShape_0aea4xy" dmnElementRef="InputData_0pgvdj9">
        <dc:Bounds height="45" width="125" x="437" y="287" />
      </dmndi:DMNShape>
    </dmndi:DMNDiagram>
  </dmndi:DMNDI>
</definitions>
```